# How do I code a mixed-effect Regression Model with RC method in SAS Studio?

Tags: sas, mixed-models, listings

Here is reading the beginning of the code,

```
data bmi;
infile "/home/my_courses/bmi.dat" firstobs=2;
input studyid age ChildhoodBMIz sex AdulthoodBMI Obesity;
run;
proc sort data=bmi;
    by studyid;
run;
```

The following is the block of code that I am having trouble with,

```
* MRM for RC method;
PROC MIXED data=bmi METHOD=ML COVTEST;
CLASS studyid;
MODEL ChildhoodBMIz = age/SOLUTION;
RANDOM INTERCEPT age/SUB=studyid TYPE=un G S cl;
ODS LISTING EXCLUDE SOLUTIONR; ODS OUTPUT SOLUTIONR=randnew SOLUTIONF=fixednew;
RUN;
```

Only, I am receiving an error that I don't quite understand.

`ERROR: The LISTING destination is not active; no select/exclude lists are available.`

How do I activate the listing destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ODS LISTING EXCLUDE SOLUTIONR;` portion of the code and it should successfully run.

The code is outputting data used by some of your graphics from your mixed model to a new dataset called `randnew`:

`ODS OUTPUT SOLUTIONR=randnew`

All modern SAS IDEs output to HTML by default. The code is excluding the old `listing` graphics destination, which looks to already be disabled in your session.  If this was autogenerated code, it is probably legacy code that no longer applies to modern SAS IDEs and should be mentioned to Tech Support.

Comment: Thank you! I was also using SOLUTIONR instead of SOLUTIONF, so that was my bad.